# безопасное копирование строки на си

Tags: c

Задался вопросом как безопасно копировать строку на си. Есть у меня строка str1 мне нужно ее скопировать в строку str2 но возможна ситуация когда в str1 не будет нуля в конце сроки, тогда возможна ситуация когда по указателю будет произведена операция перезаписи данных в области выходящей за приделы str2.
Есть решение этой проблемы ?

Comment: `когда в str1 не будет нуля в конце сроки,` А что известно про эту строку?

Comment: `strncpy(str2,str1,str2_maxlen)` [strncpy](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strncpy)  используют для этой цели, если извесна макс длинна str2. Если не извесна макс длинна str2 то задача неразрешима.

Comment: Если строка не завершена нулевым символом - то это не *строка*, а *массив символов*. Работайте с ним как с массивом, вот и все.

Comment: я когда то давно, когда не было нормальных санитайзеров, использовал функцию malloc_usable_size (это для gcc, _msize для vs), что бы знать верхнюю границу и бросать сообщение в лог с подрезанием строки. Помогло вычислить пару странных случаев. Но это только для отладки, не для "использования на каждый день). Но эти функции работают для хипа

Comment: За 'strncpy(str2,str1,str2_maxlen)' заметил следующие , инициализация нулями пространства после строки до завершения длины 'str2_maxlen'.

Comment: Да, вы правы. [strncpy](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/): "If the end of the source C string (which is signaled by a null-character) is found before num characters have been copied, destination is padded with zeros until a total of num characters have been written to it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char b[10],a[]="Мама мыла раму";
int x,i;
for (x=0,i=0;x!=sizeof(b)-1;x++,i++)//Если а<b использовать sizeof(а)-1
b[x]=a[i];
b[x++]='\0';
printf("\"%s\" длина-%d размер-%d",b,strlen(b),sizeof(b));

//Вывод: "Мама мыла" длина-9 размер-10
```

Comment: Вы реализовали руками strcpy, но вот только какая цель? на код ревью такой код точно не пройдет.

Comment: Просто постарался ответить на вопрос.

Comment: пробовать отвечать - это хорошо. Но почему весь код написан вручную, без использования библиотек, да ещё так, как будто это писал  человек в 1990 году?

Comment: Наверное потому что я и есть человек с 1990 года.))))

Comment: есть только проблема, что в этом случае, Вы ещё не могли писать код. А так ничего

Comment: Рад знакомству.

Comment: Когда то давно я писал функцию разворачивающую строку задом на перёд. Щас решил что как раз она подойдёт ессно без разворота. Убрал разворот и вот кажись проблема у человека решается.